# Plot.ly Scatter Plot not Showing all Data Points

Tags: pandas, numpy, plot, plotly

I am new to data science and I am doing some data visualization analysis with plotly dash, but I've tried different way to arrange x & y, but the graph doesn't plot all the data points.

The sample data x has 70 columns with binary data of 0 & 1, and y has data of 1, 2, 3. They are all categorical data after pandas.get_dummies treatment

Can anyone please advice? Thanks in advance!!

```
import numpy as np 
import plotly.offline as pyo
import plotly.graph_objs as go
arr_x=np.array(df2.drop("Severity_Level",1).values)
arr_y=np.array(df2["Severity_Level"].values)
data = [go.Scatter(x=arr_x, y=arr_y, mode='markers')]
pyo.plot(data, filename='scatter.html')
```

[image]

Comment: can you provide some sample data to make it reproducible?

Comment: The sample data x has 70 columns with binary data of 0 & 1, and y has data of 1, 2, 3. They are all categorical data after pandas.get_dummies treatment

Comment: Can you still show use some example rows? Using your example using dummy data I've created myself works as expected, see https://i.imgur.com/7wHt4y9.png.